# How to implement the while loop in this piece of code?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

My program ends after I enter an invalid input.  I know I need to use a `while` loop to make the user enter a number.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class AreaCircle { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // read the keyboard
        System.out.println("This program will calculate the area of a circle");
        System.out.println("Enter radius:");//Print to screen

        try {
            double r = sc.nextDouble(); // Read in the double from the keyboard
            double area = (3.14 *r * r);

            String output = "Radius: " + r + "\n";
            output = output + "Area: " + area + "\n";
            System.out.println("The area of the circle  is " + area);

        }
        catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input, please enter a number");
            //put a message or anything you want to tell the user that their input was weird.
        }
        catch( InputMismatchException e )
        {

            System.out.println("Input Mismatch, please enter a number");
            //put a message or anything you want to tell the user that there is an 
            //input mismatch.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Identify the block of code that you want to repeat; the block of code should be inside the loop body.  Determine under what conditions you want the loop to end, and that should be the bool expression that gets evaluated.  Someone will probably put up an answer, but constructing a loop is something very fundamental that I think is worth taking time to learn yourself.  If you still can't figure it out within the hour, and no one responds to your question, then I will happily submit an example myself =)

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with Swing.  Please read the tags carefully before applying them to a question.

Comment: You already asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757193/what-error-do-you-find-in-this-code-program-erro-is-it-wont-run-unless-you-type) Have you tried anything on your own??

Answer (score 0):

Just make a infinite loop around the part you want to keep doing until you get a valid input and if you get a valid input then break it.

```
while (true){
  try {
    double r = sc.nextDouble(); // Read in the double from the keyboard
    double area = (3.14 *r * r);

    String output = "Radius: " + r + "\n";
    output = output + "Area: " + area + "\n";
    System.out.println("The area of the circle  is " + area);
    break;                              <---- New code that will break the loop

  }
  catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input, please enter a number");
    //put a message or anything you want to tell the user that their input was weird.
  }
  catch( InputMismatchException e )
  {

    System.out.println("Input Mismatch, please enter a number");
    //put a message or anything you want to tell the user that there is an 
    //input mismatch.
  }
}
The execution will continue from here after break
```

Comment: The above piece of code runs into an infinite loop upon giving invalid input. Please check.

Comment: No it won't becouse the read from the input are done by sc.nextDouble().

Answer (score 0):

put  double r = sc.nextDouble(); and exception inside While loop.

put custom message inside exception catch block like "Input is not correct please enter input again. If exception occur while loop still execute.

Answer (score 0):

You rather require a do-while loop here. You use do-while loop where the block of code in the loop has to execute at least once.Here is how you will implement it:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Circle { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

          boolean invalid_input = false;    

        do
        {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // read the keyboard
        System.out.println("This program will calculate the area of a circle");
        System.out.println("Enter radius:");//Print to screen

        try {
            double r = sc.nextDouble(); // Read in the double from the keyboard
            double area = (3.14 *r * r);

            String output = "Radius: " + r + "\n";
            output = output + "Area: " + area + "\n";
            System.out.println("The area of the circle  is " + area);
                invalid_input = false;

        }
        catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
              invalid_input = true;
            System.out.println("Invalid Input, please enter a number");
            //put a message or anything you want to tell the user that their input was weird.
        }
        catch( InputMismatchException e )
        {
                invalid_input = true;
            System.out.println("Input Mismatch, please enter a number");
            //put a message or anything you want to tell the user that there is an 
            //input mismatch.
        }
        }while(invalid_input== true);



    }
}
```

Comment: @user1190386 There could be other ways to handle exceptions in Java. What i have just showed you, is an example.